# Delete every digit in a line except the first digit

Tags: shell

Good evening,

I have text file and I would like to keep only the first digit in each line or in other words: remove all digits except the first digit. To make it easy I have this file

```
$ cat file
one1
2two3
45end6
```

And I expect this output:

```
one1
2two
4end
```

Could someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is to tell `sed` to delete the 2nd occurrence of the numeric digit. Do it in several passes and you are guaranteed all the digits except the first occurrence will be deleted.

```
sed -i ':a;s/[0-9]//2;ta' file
```

`:a` defines a function labeled `a`.

`s/[0-9]//2` deletes the 2nd occurrence of a digit.

`ta` branch to function `:` labeled `a`.

Sample output:

```
one1
2two
4end
```

Comment: Thank you for this one. It's the neatest way hence I ticked this one green. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that this is totally the wrong direction, but you could do something like:

```
sed -E -e 'h; s/([0-9]).*/\1/g; x; s/[^0-9]*[0-9]//; s/[0-9]*//g; H; g; s/\n//;' input
```

Comment: I haven’t tested this so it isn’t an answer, but wouldn’t just `sed -r 's/([0-9].*)[0-9]/\1/g'` work?

Comment: @DanielH That works for this input, but fails on a line like `1foo2bar3baz`, in which the `2` is retained.

Comment: But that does point to a nice perl solution: `perl -pe '1 while s/([0-9].*)[0-9]/\1/g'`

Comment: @DanielH and William Pursell, a simple `loop` inside `sed` will work on the sample input and on `1foo2bar3baz` like `sed -i ':a;s/[0-9]//2;ta' file`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I wasn’t sure how `s///g` worked in a case like this, which is why I wasn’t sure. I’m surprised it works for `45end6` but not `1foo2bar3baz`; can you direct me to a resource that explains it better than `sed`s man page?

Comment: @DanielH The trouble is that the `g` flag won't consider overlapping matches, but the loop does.   There is some good info at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476714/is-there-a-good-online-interactive-regex-tutorial

Comment: I understand regular expressions well enough; my issue is with the details of `sed`. Neither the man page nor the info page for GNU `sed` actually specified that the `g` flag only considers non-overlapping matches; I eventually found it in [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html). My suggestion (or even what I intended to suggest, where the `.*` was lazy) wouldn’t have worked on the third line of the sample input for the same reason it wouldn’t have worked on `1foo2bar3baz`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not have a `\r` in your file (or delete that character first), so you can use that character to mark your digits.

```
sed -r 's/([0-9])/\r\1/g; s/\r//; s/\r[0-9]//' inputfile
```

First you mark all digits, than remove the marker before the first one and finally remove all digits that still have a marker.

EDIT: Replaced `s/\r([0-9])/\1/;` with `s/\r//;`

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use `expr` in POSIX shell do what you need as well, e.g.

```
while read -r line; do 
    len=$(expr match "$line" [0-9][0-9]*[A-Za-z]*)
    [ "$len" -gt '0' ] && expr substr "$line" 1 $len || 
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
done < file
```

With your data in `file`, just cut and paste the above into the command line, e.g.

```
$ while read -r line; do
>     len=$(expr match "$line" [0-9][0-9]*[A-Za-z]*)
>     [ "$len" -gt '0' ] && expr substr "$line" 1 $len ||
>     printf "%s\n" "$line"
> done < file
one1
2two
45end
```

**note:** while this is a solution using `expr match` and `expr substr`, the `sed` solutions are more efficient as you will spawn a separate subshell on each `expr` call. (but it is good to know the alternatives...)